# Change The Default Font & Size In Notes

Tags: notes.app

How can I change the default font size in Notes' `DefaultFonts.plist` on a Mac version 10.9

What I have tried:

- Go to `/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/`
- Add myself to read & write permissions.
- But when I open `DefaultFonts.plist` it stays locked.

How can I put this in?

```
<dict>
<key>FontName</key>
<string>Garamond</string>
<key>Size</key>
<integer>124</integer>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing the file with an application like TextEdit or Xcode, you also need write permission to the folder the file is in (or `en.lproj`).

You can also use another editor like nano:

```
sudo nano /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/DefaultFonts.plist
```