# Notes.app is ignoring changes I make to DefaultFonts.plist

Tags: font, notes.app

In Notes, I want to use a specific font size and style, which I'm able to set via "Show Fonts". However, when you use a bulleted list, Notes ignores the font size and style from that point on and reverts to the default font. e.g., https://www.screencast.com/t/MGYxbjOn1fdQ

Maybe this is a bug. So to work around it, I changed DefaultFonts.plist file (/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/DefaultFonts.plist). However, the application doesn't seem to be picking up these changes, so I'm still in the same situation. Any idea WHY Notes is ignoring the changes I make to DefaultFonts.plist? (Or, any other ideas on how to address this odd behavior with bulleted lists in Notes?) Thanks.

Comment: As a workaround, create your note and then select all text and set the font and size.

Comment: yup. That's exactly what I do. But then when you start a bulleted list, Notes ignores the font you've selected and reverts to default. So then you have to constantly select all text and set font and size, each time you do a bulleted list in your doc/note. See my link to screenshot above.